# How to write a string containing private ssh key to a file?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

I am using Azure DevOps for my pipeline. I have a copy of the public and private keys. The public key is already added to the server via the creation process using Terraform.

For testing purposes, I have created a variable $key to store the private key. The variable is part of the DevOps pipeline and it can be retrieved by the bash script on the build server.

I want to use that key to SSH to a remote server. When I try to write the $key to a file and then use it e.g.

```
ssh user@10.10.10.10 -i keyfile
```

I get asked for a passphrase. I believe that this is to do with the format of the private key file. It appears as a long string without line breaks.

The private key appears as follows when echoed:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAiyaucjBXLAy4yEFKez7b1uBUNmkycyAeOE3f9a37XqX9WRj46mH/cUE+18Oc DZWQyu5Pei3wRarv19E6XMLYcis63pbogncdIqHlvc25QLHKz+mZ6TQm/CDBKhK5GHifJSODcsNa YH7Gwy7y3T46LOicoz+cKhPm7McQ3uthSSsEZQyjlnOhQ+s4cjPa29rszlnp8HvMm+hniouCD2Kh b9/xv0yomh1d+pd3RtvdksqX4Zac0vmshpeMYZEVTPabhkfJksd8VnYYzGjjlf0Axxf+gSEM8Ime LGtdcefl4S/lNwLuYBZxjgqbSl23oHsT/ZmiWxIXfqBOHm6mcv+qLQIDAQABAoIBAGF6aX4Iqyhq iQ+P3XNU54AxigzLyNGpUEI1G4zpokv9j+rYeZcHq4BVKobPuwQxIEtogjie8dB8HKRdJ7tPq3zf F9BSevLaKojWTTCXaw0M/3yCspURObYp4+drUkr4RNQpeq3sd+VdKjQVMYEXVH2dPg2GRAmeA4kf MoxW68Hq1w2bByUnrrehoidu46r6KBlQyUApJmu5y2Xbo5izbyEoRQoGF0Sz2EHW2AckxTwMkovF 78dh8L3b3DAd0aAF8ijewA/aCy+gSzZzihGcpFMKVxVh5McrzssS74ThjaeKKnDRIPlP02je0rtf DOuWoivc9RP/o5nJvNU2qzLri4ECgYEA7edgmf/FVIrIBc8QqWpvF0WYhWMusgBm8DUvOGnnevPo MFRgNTAjl+rDKfTvOTnphYrEKYoLJTDpNZGvopSUsra5IANAcHSxM8dpUyXGqIlIC9rdzOQNZhON Ss/f4d9wT1fX8mWaIPiC0wC/s1V9fCRKDKARhc4mtIKlm+S7Wj0CgYEAlbxTLuoHN6Na7UOoPpp8 HEPGGItHx/QFHLwFuhe663xLaFIXqJsVgQUd88dUs5lRZ6ydGba6LeUNEOvFvHiSV7cj0YydvyJJ 7wjlu5Ge13fYTNm2uEDDhARLBum2Rx1wwBD/ovsjnevNjZeYU9ahZhiMjIv90RT7mTDLGiNBvrEC gYBWfXHfSt9gtvu1MOxryygMG98xTzeguwixd4RtTAM97gKR33sCmze1eUHutP9rnKRLSoG6YFdg 9AE02nwx7TaKKmfvPX9l4uaxXmPqOKeaih5JQQ61+Irue1k4w44vPd5E2jjGBS4dontdXr5S4le2 lDLfmCoGrUXhBkZTALskOQKBgDRr2jNye1RfPFYUebJxI0JB9/hfyqGWLLQCn36nECmhOkUreFzu 7nhc8j+GaYD3DCjfpaB6+HNY3VovMOrqy1EqLMAQGqnvtzKYStWABbwpmPBOyEl5Yvm1Bw9Egywi gna7fMPyaGXBSBVqHUo8ugSkU5Bg8ltgnTTkgDaGYV4BAoGBAKKAaI7hajJKYkWgbW5L744f2XvX coi5CAEdqQ+Bfah/THt+s57tfAOAiQWutnmv7vzLlWjiHip+MrJYnQ+Whb5VzeDS1qNYbcZfgNNl 6OOkPcq7v0NVczeaoGWtKFdL4ZCcwciw08YolSthBUvY8ZAZoLoyE3YoBFaa7VKil1iO -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

What is the best way to format the string and write it to a .pem file?

Or if this is a silly question, where is the best place to store a private key file for automation?

An alternative way that I have done this for testing is to store the private key as part of a repository and then pulled that down during build. This method works fine but I fear it is not "best practice".

Comment: I think you should elaborate a bit on the hows of "I have created a variable $key". And you don't tell us if and how you added this to the server side.

Comment: @pLumo Ok, updated the question.

Comment: I see, please add the output of `ssh -vvv user@10.10.10.10 -i keyfile`

Comment: Still don't get how that would work. SSH uses private/public key pair, so you need two files ... Sure that this is the right key you're getting?

Comment: @pLumo - updated based on your comments

Comment: @pa4080 the private key file (which I have) is not password protected. Its when I copy those key data into a variable and then try to write the contents of the variable to a file on the remote server, the passphrase is prompted. I think that this is misleading and is being caused by the format of the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure if this counts as an answer but I got it working. I used the "Install SSH key" task in Azure DevOps to store the public and private keys. You can paste the keys in as strings into this task and it will install the keys and make them available for use with other servers.

More information about the [SSH Key Task](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-ssh-key?view=azure-devops)